# Primefaces Button color uniform not gradient

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I want to set a primefaces button color uniform, not at the top lighter and darker at the bottom. How could I override PrimeFaces button style?

Answer (score 0):

Set css-attribute "background-color" to whatever you want...

override the .ui-button-text definition from primefaces.

You can do that by implementing you own style-libraray, or your own css-file and reference this in your xhtml.